# What's the solution of this Raven's matrix?

Tags: pattern, visual

I'm practicing with Raven's Matrices but I don't understand this one. What's the solution and why? Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it's this one

> [image]

My reasoning is

> **First set of figures**
>
> Take the second figure and "lay" it, rotating left 
>  [image: Step 1]
>
> Overlay the first figure on it (transparent red lines, 2nd figure), and then remove overlapping lines (opaque red line, 3rd figure), leaving you with the 3rd figure.
>  [image]
>
>  **2nd set**
>  Same schema, top line is overlapping. Remove it and leave the right and bottom ones
>
>  **3rd set**
>
>  Same schema, but this time no lines are overlapping, so we are leaving all of them

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the correct solution but I'd never guessed by myself... Thanks! :)